# c++ Increase pointer size without return new pointer

Tags: c++, realloc

My teacher has me complete this(the main is hidden) and i wonder why i got an infinite loop with this solution.
Task:
Complete this function:

```
void pad_left(char *a, int n) {
}

// if length of a greater than n, do nothing
// else insert '_' util a 's length is n
```

Some case i got an segmentfault
I try realloc but it return new ptr
My solution

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

void printChar(char *a) {
    int i = 0;
    while(a[i] != '\0') cout << a[i];
    cout << endl;
}


void insert_begin(char *a, int n) {
    for(int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    a[n+1] = '\0';
}

void pad_left(char *a, int n) {
    int len = n - strlen(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        insert_begin(a, strlen(a));
    }
}
```

Here is full code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

void printChar(char *a) {
    int i = 0;
    while(a[i] != '\0') cout << a[i];
    cout << endl;
}


void insert_begin(char *a, int n) {
    for(int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        a[i] = a[i-1];
    }
    a[n+1] = '\0';
}

void pad_left(char *a, int n) {
    int len = n - strlen(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        insert_begin(a, strlen(a));
    }
}


int main() {

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    char a[5] = "test";
    pad_left(a, 10);

    printChar(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the line `while(a[i] != '\0') cout << a[i];` you should increment `i`.

Comment: `char a[5] = "test"; pad_left(a, 10);` - `a` is an array of size 5, not 10 - you cannot write to any index higher than 4 without invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: Maybe try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your `insert_begin` and `pad_left` functions. There's no way there should be two nested loops required to handle padding a string with underscores. (Not to mention nothing in your code will place an underscore anywhere.)

Comment: You can't modify the size of a static array. Moreover, the function as given by your teacher is ill-formed. Indeed, if you wish to modify the given (dynamically allocated) array, you should take either a reference or a pointer to the given pointer to the first element of the array (and you also need the size of the array btw).

Comment: I think i got the prolerm now, the pointer is actually from an allocated memory, just ignore the size of array and do it.. i think so
I got some prolerm with first time on stackoverflow, thank you guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you need some background information.

```
void pad_left(char *a, int n) {
}
char a[5] = "test";
pad_left(a, 10);
```

This is going to be a significant problem. First, you can't realloc for two reasons. First, char a[5] is a fixed array -- not an allocated array. When you pass it to pad_left, that doesn't change. realloc() does a free of the old pointer, but you can't do that, and it will cause problems. So you cannot use realloc in your solution unless you make sure the strings came from allocated memory. And you can't assume that.

So put realloc aside. You can't use that.

Next, char a[5] only allocates 5 bytes. If you start writing beyond that range (by passing in 10 to your method), you're going to step on other places. This is absolutely bad.

So... Without testing it, the rest of your code seems reasonable. You can probably get a good test if you do this:

```
char a[100] = "test";
pad_left(a, 10);
```

You'll have allocated plenty of space for padding. Try this and see if you get further.

Comment: I think i got the prolerm now, the pointer pass to function is actually from much more allocated memory than i thought 
Besides, i've got some better understanding about realloc, thank you so much